# How do I generate a 404 Error in PHP?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I wanted to know if there is a way to simulate a 404 error in PHP. For example, I have this URL: `www.mydomain.com/user/[Username]` which redirects to /profile.php?user=[username]. I want the server to show my 404 Error page if the username is not registered.

**[PHP]** Here it is some sample code:

```
<?
   if (notRegistered($_GET['user'])) {
        // Throw 404 Error
   }
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's 401 Error. I dont's know how to do that with a 404..

Comment: You put a 404 error message in there instead of a 401 one!

Comment: Didn't work.. header( '404 Not Found' );

Comment: Use the code from the **answer** not the question!

Comment: Sorry, my bad.. It doesn't work anyway => header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found', true, 404);

Comment: The answer: `header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized', true, 401);` obviously in your case you want 404, and Not Found instead of Unauthorized.

Comment: Do you get an error when attempting to use it? Does it just display the page anyway?

Comment: Nope, just shows the page normally.

Comment: It [works fine here](http://test-cases.dorward.me.uk/stackoverflow/20575638/example.php). Either you are misinterpreting what you are seeing or some other part of your code is breaking it and you should look in your error log.

Comment: @JoaquínO — It shows the page normally? If you output the page, then the user will still see the page. If you send a 404 header, it is customary to send an HTML document explaining that it is a 404 error page, but it is perfectly possible to send something that doesn't look like one at all.

Comment: Why is the header useful for me then?

Comment: So search engines don't index the page, for the benefit of your test suite, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTTP reports the status code via the headers. Use the [`header()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function in PHP to set the status code:

```
if (notRegistered($_GET['user'])) {
     header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 404 Not Found');
     exit(1);
}
```

Also you may want to send an error page to the browser:

```
if (notRegistered($_GET['user'])) {
     header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 404 Not Found');
     readfile('path/to/error404.html');
     exit(1);
}
```

[`$_SERVER\['SERVER_PROTOCOL'\]`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) will contain `HTTP/1.0` or `HTTP/1.1`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me..

Comment: What does `Doesn't work` mean?

Comment: I've tried the first option, and nothing seemed to happen.. So, you mean that I have to include my 404 error page manually?

Comment: yes, exactly... The easiest thing for testing would be: `echo 'Not found';`.. You may prepare candy 404.html's afterwards. ;)

Comment: So there is no way to show the browser's 404 page??

Comment: "browser's" 404 page is always coming from server. You misunderstood that

Comment: What I mean is: if the server sends a 404 error header, why doesn't the browser show a 404 error?

Comment: The browser just shows what the server sends. That's the same for success pages as for error pages. Only if a server isn't available the browser shows a custom error page. (That's because the server is just not reachable and can't sed an error page)

Comment: Oh, I thought that if the server sends '404 error', the browser would show it's 404 error page.. Knowing this, why is it useful for me to send the '404 header'?

Comment: You need to understand [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) and it's [status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Comment: Nevermind.. I'll just include the error page.. Thanks.

Comment: One last question: if I use `header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 404 Not Found');` and then `var_dump(headers_list());` I can't see the header I just set.. Is it OK?

Comment: have you used echo before? or other output?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43152/discussion-between-joaquin-o-and-hek2mgl)